# Открытие сайта на мобильном

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://broker-sberbank.ru
Как сделать так чтобы с мобильного сайт открывался в полный разворот, а не на 1\4. Я так понимаю, что то связанное с адаптивностью. Но вроде бы все нормально проставил. А все равно.

Comment: Что-то адаптивности не видно совсем. Вот [полезный инструмент](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?utm_source=psi&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=uxresults&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbroker-sberbank.ru%2F)

Comment: У вас сайт недоступен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял из вопроса, речь идёт о том, чтобы масштабировать сайт по ширине окна устройства. В таком случае, добавьте в блок `<head></head>` строку

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Если нужно, чтобы сайт отображался по всей ширине устройства без возможности масштабирования, используйте этот вариант.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Хм! Я об этом читал, пробовал так сделать. Но почему то не работает именно в WordPress. Пробовал добавлять в header.php но толку чуть. Может быть знаете куда именно нужно это вписывать в шаблонах WP?

Comment: Отредактируйте код страницы так, чтобы теги `<html>` и `<body>` не повторялись. Объедините, по возможности, все сегменты `<head>` в один. Тогда `viewport` должен заработать.

Answer (score 0):

У вас на странице ТРИЖДЫ в разных местах открывается тег `<html>` и все вложенные в него, включая `head` и `body`. Устраните для начала эту ошибку, вполне возможно, что этого будет достаточно для того, чтобы конструкция `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` в итоге заработала